# Call Stored Procedures in a java client application

Tags: java, rest, stored-procedures, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x

So, my problem is: I've developed some **REST services with Jersey**, in **Glassfish 3.1.2**, that were generated from my **MySQL database**. Then I've implemented Basic-Authentication. That's all working fine.

Now, I'm developing a **client application** to consume those services. I've used `Apache HttpClient` to the authentication, and I've already tried the GET method, and the PUT method. I can obtain the values from my DataBase, and update others, with the aid of a JSON object.

But how can I use the **Stored Procedures** that I have in my database, to do a PUT/POST and update my DataBase??

Thanks

Comment: Check the docs for [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about here. Are you defining SQL queries to be run, on the client side (really hope not)? Or are you asking about how to implement the server side resource methods?

Comment: @NilsH, can you tell me the difference between **Callable Statement** and **Prepared Statement**?

Comment: A CallableStatment is a subclass of PreparedStatement that offers operations suitable for calling stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JDBC, something like this

```
cs = this.con.prepareCall("{call SHOW_SUPPLIERS()}");
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) 
{
    String supplier = rs.getString("SUP_NAME");
    String coffee = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
    System.out.println(supplier + ": " + coffee);
}
```

As an example, see following documentation (where I got the above code from)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Comment: But where does the fact that I am using **REST services** enter here? So I don't use the POST/PUT methods?

Comment: REST and JDBC are two completely different concerns, so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve? Usually, POST is used to create a REST resource, PUT (or lately, PATCH) is used to update a resource, and GET is used to fetch a resource. I can't see how that relates to calling a stored procedure other than reading/saving data to implement those services.